# how to host java website which is developed in red hat 5 using notepad and not using Eclipse or any IDE

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, web

During my college time i have developed a java website in red hat 5 ,
On tomcat server with mysql as DB.
I havent use any IDE (Eclipse,NetBeans etc) for it.
I have developed it using notepad.
I have no clue of deploying any java website.
I tried importing my java website in the eclipse but it was giving lots of errors.
If anyone can help me that will be great !!

Please get my project folder on below link:

https://jumpshare.com/b/ppGP9oibkrTvVLtw9YxW

I had this directory in my Tomcat folder.

Please help.

Comment: just move your java source code into `src` folder, and html/jsp files into `web-page`.  I develop java application in `VIM` with some plugins and `eclim` to assistant. I prefer to develop java in edior rather than IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you just want to run the web app on your local server :**

Install Tomacat.

Copy the ty154 folder to the web app folder

Start tomcat. If your code was working, then it will show up at something like the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/ty154/
```

**If you just want to run the web app on a tomcat hosted server by uploading your web app folder :**

Copy the ty154 folder to the web app folder.

Assuming that your hosting url is

```
http://neer.hosting.com/
```

then goto the following url

```
http://neer.hosting.com/ty154/
```

For some of the hostings you might have to restart your tomcat server.

**Deploying using war files :**

Also some of the hostings have some special ways to deploy. They might ask you to upload your WAR file. Here are the commands for generating the WAR file.

```
cd /to/your/folder/location
jar -cvf my_web_app.war *
```

Mostly uploading the WAR file to the web app folder on the remote hosting should suffice. Only thing is that you might have to restart your tomcat server.

**NOTE :** Some of the free hosting have their own steps for deployment. Refer to their deployment help documents. It will help you better.

Comment: HI neer thanks for your answer, but i want to deploy my website on a free hosting domain. so can you suggest me how can i do that please.

Comment: Hi Harish, I have updated the answer for 3 different ways of deploying including remote hostings. Also if its ok then please let me know the free hosting. If it helped then do vote and like the answer :)